# How do I make a view of taxonomy terms with no spaces between lines (no Views HTML)?

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

I want to make a view to list 100 taxonomy terms like this:

Term 1, Term 2, Term 3, Term 4, ... Term 100

I made a view of taxonomy terms.

Here are the settings:

```
Format: Unformatted list
Settings: Add views row classes *unchecked*

Fields: Taxonomy term: Name
Formatter: Plain text
Link to the Taxonomy term *unchecked*

Style settings
Customize field HTML *checked* (none)
Customize label HTML *checked* (none)
Customize field and label wrapper HTML *checked* (none)
Create a CSS class *unchecked*
Add default class *unchecked*
Use field template *unchecked*

Rewrite results
Override the output of this field *checked*
Text: {{ name }},
```

However, the output looks like this:

```
<div>Term 1,</div>
<div>Term 2,</div>
```

This div puts all of the terms on new lines.  Is there a way to get rid of it within the Views settings?  Running Drupal 8.3.5.

Comment: why you not use some lines of css for getting display like this Term 1, Term 2, Term 3, Term 4, ... Term 100

Comment: @code.rider If possible, I would rather get Drupal to not add tags I don't need instead of writing CSS to override the default.

Comment: then you must have to override the template create template file for your view and then remove div structure from the template have no other way